# Comparing Array to 2D Array- Morse Code for Microcontroller

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, microcontroller

I'm having to complete a morse code project using a TI MSP430G2553 microcontroller to flash the morse code. I'm trying to get the program to print out dot and dash for each letter before messing with the microcontroller's flash. I'm unsure how to compare an array to a 2D array. I'd like for the comparison to then check whether a dot, dash or space is found when looking at the corresponding letter in the array. Here is what I have so far.

I've tried setting the arrays to one another by doing "if (str[i] == morse_array[j][k])" but I only got the message that I can't compare a pointer and an integer. Any guidance on steps to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void time_delay(int sec);


void main(void)
{
unsigned int i = 0;
unsigned int j, k;

char str [] = "Go Knights";
char* morse_array [36][2] = {{".-", "A"}, {"-...", "B"}, {"-.-.", "C"}, {"-..", "D"}, {".", "E"}, \
    {"..-.", "F" }, { "--.", "G"}, {"....", "H"}, {"..", "I"}, {".---", "J"}, {"-.-", "K"}, {".-..", "L"}, \
    {"--", "M"}, {"-.", "N"}, {"---", "O"}, {".--.", "P"}, {"--.-", "Q"}, {".-.", "R"}, {"...", "S"}, \
    {"-", "T"}, {"..-", "U"}, {"...-", "V"}, {".--", "W"}, {"-..-", "X"}, {"-.--", "Y"}, {"--..", "Z"}, \
    {"-----", "0"}, {".----", "1"}, {"..---", "2"}, {"...--", "3"}, {"....-", "4"}, {".....", "5"}, {"-....", "6"}, \
    {"--...", "7"}, {"---..", "8"}, {"----.", "9"}};



    for(i=0; i< strlen(str); i++){
        for (j=0; j <= i; j++) {

            if (strncmp(morse_array[i][j], &str[i], strlen(str)) == 0){
                if(str[i] == '.'){
                    printf("DOT");
                    time_delay(200);
                }
                else if (str[i] == '-'){
                    printf("DASH");
                    time_delay(600);
                }

                else if (str[i] == ' '){
                    printf("SPACE");
                    time_delay(1400);
                }
            }
        }
    time_delay (1400);
    }
    printf("start program again");
    return;
}

void time_delay(int sec) {
// Converting time into milli_seconds
int milliSeconds = 1000 * sec;

clock_t start = clock();

while (clock() < start + milliSeconds)
    ;
}
```

Comment: `str[i]` is a single character. `morse_array[j][k]` is a pointer to a string. A good solution is to convert `morse_array` into an array of structures. The kludgey solution is to use `morse_array[j][k][0]`.

Comment: You have a `for (i...)` loop nested inside another one.  You need to change one of them to use a different variable, e.g. `j`, to avoid having them clobber each other.

Comment: Also you can't pass `morse_array[i]` to `strncmp`, since it expects a `char *`, not a `char **`.  You need to add a second index, e.g. `morse_array[i][j]` to get a `char *`.

Comment: @TomKarzes that has helped with getting rid of the warning that I was seeing. The next issue appears to be the `str[i] == '.'` and I've tried replacing `str` with `morse_array[i][j][0] == '.' ` but this is skipped as well. is there a different way to check whether a dot or dash is present?